# Drupal: upload progress bar in lighttpd?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, lighttpd

So, everybody told me that Drupal can run on lighttpd without any difference, but there is one and it is horrible: there is not PECL Progressing Bar.

[image]

Is there any way to make it work ? I need a progress for my customer, they are uploading big files using the CMS...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC provides the same support for RFC 1867 (the upload progress), although I'm not sure if Drupal recognizes it.  I'd recommend giving it a shot, it certainly can't hurt.  Once you [install APC](http://www.howtoforge.com/integrating-apc-into-php5-and-lighttpd-fedora9), add this to your php.ini: `apc.rfc1867=1`

Hope that works for you!